# what is a nice way to show that developable surfaces must have a principal curvature=0?

Tags: differential-geometry

So a developable surface can be parametrized as

$x(s, t)=\alpha(s)+t \beta(s)$

I can see that $\beta(s)$ is the direction of the principal curvature plane with k=0, but why is it the minimum or maximum curvature plane cutting through that point? Is $\alpha(s)$ a plane curve on the other principal curvature plane?

Comment: What is definition of developable surface that you use? Wikipedia defines it precisely as surface with zero curvature

Comment: I'm using this definition: x(s,t)=α(s)+tβ(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector you have given $x(s, t)=\alpha(s)+t \beta(s)$ is a ruled surface with generator $ \beta(s)$.

It may *or may not be developable* depending on tangent vector triple product.

It is developable if $ (T, \beta(s),\beta{'}(s)) = 0  $

and skew ( twisted with negative Gauss curvature K)  if

$(T, \beta(s),\beta{'}(s)) \ne 0. $

$ K = k_1\cdot k_2 = 0  $ is necessary and sufficient condition. When parametric lines of principal curvature $k_1=0 $ for $K=0$ then that parameter defines the straight edge or regression line of a developable surface.